# Dynamically change line color dcc.Graph Plotly Dash between annotations

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm writing a 'template creation' app using the dcc.Graph [image annotation features in Plotly Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/annotations).

The user adds multiple rectangles for specific features in the image (an invoice) and my callback captures the coordinates of each rectangle via the *relayoutData* variable. I want to use a different color for each rectangle, but can't figure out how to do it.

- It seems like the only way to change the newshapes *fillcolor*
  property is to replace the whole figure, but then I lose all previous shapes

All and any help appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

I have just found the following demo that does exactly what I am trying to do:

- https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-image-annotation/